# jpa version cascade

Tags: java, jpa

### JSR 220: Enterprise JavaBeansTM,Version 3.0

### section 3.4.2

### paragraph 3

*All non-relationship fields and properties and all relationships owned by the entity are
included in version checks.*

**My Question:**
What does "owned by the entity" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In two-sided relationships, one side "owns" the relationship, meaning that the corresponding table contains the foreign key. (It is the "many" side in many-to-one relationships, or the side where you don't specify the `mappedBy` attribute in all other kinds of relationships.)

You can find a detailed explanation in the Java EE tutorial's section on [direction in entity relationships](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqi).